# first_or_create equivalent in ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

### Setup

A [Phoenix](https://www.phoenixframework.org) 1.4.11 application with this resource:

```
mix phx.gen.html Institutions SchoolType school_types name
```

### Problem

I want to find the first `school_type` with a given name. If that doesn't exist I want to create it. In ActiveRecord I'd use `first_or_create`.

I have this code which works. But it doesn't look nice and probably there is a better more cleaner way to solve this problem.

```
school_type_name = "Example"

if school_type_name != nil do
  query =
    from s in SchoolType,
      where: s.name == ^school_type_name,
      limit: 1

  case Repo.one(query) do
    nil ->
      {:ok, _school_type} =
        Institutions.create_school_type(%{
          name: school_type_name
        })

    _ ->
      nil
  end

  school_type = Repo.one(query)
end
```

How can I solve this cleaner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you might see from the source code, [`first_or_create`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create) executes two queries against the database if there is no record yet

```rb
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb, line 103
def first_or_create(attributes = nil, &block) # :nodoc:
  first || create(attributes, &block)
end
```

To mimic this behaviour, you should avoid executing two queries for the case when the record already exists.

```rb
school_type =
  case Repo.one(query) do
    nil ->
      {:ok, new} =
        Institutions.create_school_type(%{
          name: school_type_name
        })
      new

    found -> found # it’s already there!
  end
```